sqlite3.dll Not Found in .NET 8 MAUI Project on Android
I have created a new MAUI .NET 8 project and migrated the Xamarin forms project code.
As part of this migration, I am using the following package:
<PackageReference Include="Mono.Data.Sqlite" Version="1.0.61" />

when I try to open a database connection on Android in Visual Studio 2022 (windows), , I encounter an exception indicating that sqlite3.dll is not found.
The exception message I receive is:
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found.
Note: This exception happening only on Android, It's working properly in iOS.
I also tried in the mac system. Still facing the same issue.
Please help us to resolve this issue.

I create a new project and reproduce your problem. I found the Mono.Data.Sqlite Version="1.0.61" package targets .NET Framework 4.0. And it's last updating is 11/5/2018.
The visual studio also showed warning:

Warning (active)  NU1701      Package 'Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net8.0-android34.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

So you can check the official document about the .NET MAUI local databases and use the sqlite-net-pcl instead.
